# I'm trying to consolidate my code...why can't I do this?

Tags: javascript, jquery

If you can't tell by my other questions, I'm a self-taught newb. I'm trying to consolidate some of my js code. I have 2 divs, with class a0 and a1. I'd like to attach a mouseenter event to each (same event).

Here's my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g2DQB/1/), which is (hopefully) self-explanatory. .a0 and .a1 are my original code and .f0 and .f1 represents my (failed) attempt to consolidate. Why can't I do a "for" loop (or, if I can, why do I always end up w/ value of "2" for i?)?

(If there's a way I can do it in jquery, that's fine)

See above fiddle for full demo:

```
$(".a0").on("mouseenter",function(){
        $(this).html("value: 0");
});
$(".a1").on("mouseenter",function(){
        $(this).html("value: 1");
});

/* my failed attempt to consolidate the above code */
for (var i=0; i<2; i++){ 
    $(".f"+i).on("mouseenter",function(){
        $(this).html("value: "+ i);
    });
}
```

Comment: One of the best tips for a "newbie": Learn to give variables, functions, classes etc. *meaningful* names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Quick & Dirty

```
$(".a0, .a1").on("mouseenter",function(){
  $(this).html("value: " + ($(this).hasClass('a0') ? 0 : 1));
});
```

#### More elegant

To resolve your question in a more elegant way, let's first understand why your code does not work.

You are defining two callbacks that will read into the value of i.

However, i will be already set to 2 when your mouse will enter the element.

You can use a closure to prevent this :

```
for (var i=0; i<2; i++){ 
  (function(j) {
    $(".f"+i).on("mouseenter",function(){
      $(this).html("value: "+ j);
    });
  })(i);
}
```

In this case, the value of i is captured into j and won't be changed when the callback is called.

Here is a [Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6TNqc/)

Comment: IMO yuck, because not extensible, and avoids teaching about the underlying issue.

Comment: @Dave...good points....his code works but would love to learn a more extensible solution.

Comment: Indeed, this code is just here to be tiny, this is not the best solution if you will have lots of other classes to deal with.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that i is a reference, and by the time your handler is called it is === 2
The following works for me.

```
var assignME = function (i) {
    $(".f"+i).on("mouseenter",function(){
        $(this).html("value: "+ i);
    });
};

for (var i=0; i<2; i++){
    assignME(i);
}
```